# How to find files that only contain alphanumeric characters?

Tags: bash, grep, find

How to find files that only contain alphanumeric characters and `[áéíóúñ.,¿?¡!()]`?

I have some sparse plain text files and I need to separate them from scripts and any other thing, they're just poetries in spanish so it's unlikely that the contain `[#></:]` for example.
I came with

```
sudo find . -type f -not -path '*/.??*/*' -exec file {}  \; \
  | grep ": Unicode text, UTF-8 text"$ \
  | cut -d: -f1 \
  | while read file; do 
     grep -iv '[a-z0-9\.\/_\-áéíóúñ]' "$file" || echo $file
    done
```

but it matches lines and I need to match the entire file.

Edit: At least what worked for me was:

```
sudo find . -type f -not -path "*/.Trash-*/*" -not -path '*/.??*/*' -exec file {} \;|
grep ": Unicode text, UTF-8 text"$|
cut -d: -f1|
while read file do 
grep -ivq "^[a-z0-9\.\/_\-\ \,\"áéíóúñ\!¿¡?\(\)]*$" "$file"||
echo "$file">>/tmp/textlocation ; done
```

The trivial solution of adding ^ and $ did the difference. The -L solution listed here may work and is more elegant but mine solution did the job.

Comment: Do you have many extensions of files?

Comment: @Quasímodo, yeah, it's my own and I don't use semicolons, anyway I can Improve myself the answers if something is missing but suere it will not contain # : or /

Comment: Do you also want to allow blanks and newlines?

Comment: @they yes poetry have them between verses

Answer (score 2):

You can use GNU `grep` instead if I understand you correctly, searching the files that *don't match* the `[#></:]` set of characters:

```
$ grep -Lr '[#></:]'
```

- `-L` will list the files that do not match the pattern

  > -L, --files-without-match
  > Suppress normal output; instead print the name of each input file from which no output would normally have been printed.  The scanning will stop on the first
  > match.
- `-r` will search recursively

  > -r, --recursive
  > Read all files under each directory, recursively, following symbolic links only if they are on the command line.  Note that if no file operand is given, grep
  > searches the working directory.  This is equivalent to the -d recurse option.

You can also add the `-Z` option in case you need to perform some action on the files other than listing then.

Comment: +1, much better than my idea (which was to use `perl -0`).  You could speed that up with `-m 1` to skip to the next file on the first line in that matches the unwanted pattern - it would skip scripts, for example, after the first line (`#!`).  Also, probably should be a bracket expression `[#></:]` otherwise grep will try to match that exact sequence of characters instead of any one of them.   And maybe use `-Z` for NUL-separated output *if* the script is going to do anything with the files other than just list them.

Comment: @cas added your suggestions (and correction) to the answer, thanks!

Comment: hum, is this right? If I've understood correctly, `-v` looks for _lines_ not matching the pattern, and then `-l` prints files where any line meets the condition. And with `-v`, that's files that have at least one line that does not match the pattern. E.g. `printf '%s\n' 'foo' '::' > test.txt` and the grep would match `test.txt`. You'd need `-L`/`--files-without-match` from GNU grep. Or a shell loop around `grep -q`, inverting the sense. Or `-z` and the assumption that the files don't have NULs, and hence just one NUL-terminated "line".

Comment: @ilkkachu thanks! I edited the answer with the GNU `-L` option.

Comment: @cas according to the (GNU) manual both `-l` and `-L` stop scanning after the first match, so `-m1` wouldn't be needed.

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity you're right. i keep forgetting that because i'm used to using -m1 when i want to match.

Answer (score 0):

I would try the `-q` option : « Quiet;  do  not  write  anything  to  standard output.  Exit immediately with zero status if any match is found, even  if an  error  was  detected. »

This avoids printing anything and enable you to get the return code.

Note also that an alphanumeric only line is `"^[a-z0-9\.\/_\-áéíóúñ]*$"`
(With a `^`, `*` and `$`)
Then I would type

```
grep -ivq "^[a-z0-9\.\/_\-áéíóúñ]*$" || echo $file
```

You may need to add some characters : spaces, comma… if you don’t, many poetries wont pass !

Comment: Note that within a double-quoted string, things like `\.`, `\/`, and `\-` expands to `.`, `/`, and `-`.  Note also that the `-` then probably defines a range of characters between `_` and `á`, which may not make sense. Also, the ``\`` character itself is literal within `[...]`, as are `.` and `/`.

Comment: @they, no, double-quotes leave the backslashes except in front of the few characters that are special within double-quotes. (dquotes, backslashes, dollars and backticks, I think.) `"\."` is the same as `'\.'` or `\\.`, but of course `"\$"` removes the backslash and is the same as `'$'` or `\$`. The dash might be suspect though, I'm not sure you can escape it inside brackets _in BRE_. (Perl-style regexes are different.) If I didn't get lost in the negations, I think that command accepts the backslash the same as letters, but not the dash. `'^[-a-z0-9./_áéíóúñ]*$'` might be better.

Comment: @ilkkachu Hm. Yes. I'm getting the quoting rules confused.  In any case, the use of backslashes within `[...]` is obviously not doing what the user thinks they do.